# EntryPoint Classes & Modules in GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

GWT code structure is really getting hard for me to follow :(. 
As per my understandings,

1. Modules references Entry Point classes.
2. When a module is loaded entry point classes referenced on it get initiated, and onModuleLoad() of corresponding classes will get executed
3. HTML host pages need to include a nocache.js file (only if it needs to work with entry point classes)

If my understandings are correct,

1. In standard web development platforms like asp .net an aspx page refer to a servlet. **Here mulitple html pages can refer to a single entry point class.Why?**(and this is much complicated?)
2. **When I can expect a module to load?** If multiple modules & html pages are there, how we can assign modules to html pages, so that a particular module will load when user requests an html page?
3. I have an Async service call implemented at onModuleLoad(). And want to call this only for index.html page. **But How can I identify the html page at onModuleLoad()?**
4. **Why Google proposes GWT for GAE app development?**

I am newbie in GWT. I want to follow a good programmig structure for GAE app development. Corrections and suggestions are expecting...

Answer (score 2):

Pls see this to understand how a GWT project is organized: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects

(Bootstrap is also described there, how application loads from the html page)

I think the main thing is that everything compiles to one javascript file. 
The app runs in a single page.
In .gwt.xml you define the entry-point of your app. 
Also you specify what other modules you inherit. 
This is very similar to java or .net applications where you specify what other packages you need. The modules are like libraries. For example if you needed to use JSON you would inherit the json module. Also I don't think to you are obliged to use GWT on the front